# How to group by multiple columns and then transpose in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, data-analysis

I have some data that I want to group by on multiple columns, perform an aggregation function on, and then transpose into different columns using Hive.

For example, given this input

### Input:

```
hr  type value
01  a    10
01  b    20
01  c    50
01  a    30
02  c    10
02  b    90
02  a    80
```

I want to produce this output:

### Output:

```
hr  a_avg  b_avg  c_avg
01  20     20     50
02  80     90     10
```

Where there is one distinct column for each distinct `type` in my input. `a_avg` corresponds to the average `a` value for each hour.

How can I do this in Hive? I am guessing I might need to make use of https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Collect-UDFs

So far the best I can think of is to use multiple group-by clauses, but that won't transpose the data into multiple columns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily *need* to use Brickhouse, but it will definitely make it easier. Here is what I'm thinking, something like

```
select hr
  , type_map['a'] a_avg
  , type_map['b'] b_avg
  , type_map['c'] c_avg
from (
  select hr
    , collect(type, avg_value) type_map -- Brickhouse collect; creates a map
  from (
    select hr
      , type
      , avg( value ) avg_value
    from db.table
    group by hr, type ) x
  group by hr ) y
```

Comment: The one-level inner query says "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:11 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'avg_value'"