# How to transpose a table with a categorical variable in hive that has many levels?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, transpose, hiveql

I have a table with a cagtegorical variable that has many levels:

```
ID      Level
8257    1
2491    2
9693    3
7217    4
3931    5
7943    6
3482    7
1566    8
7905    9
5645    10
7528    11
7902    12
1695    13
1986    14
9109    15
```

I want to transpose the matrix to create a dummy variable for each ID that is 1 when the level is present and 0 otherwise.

IMPORTANT:  I don't want to hard code a long series of case when statements because in my actual data I have over 1500 levels.  In the end I want 1500 dummy variables.

My data should look like this in the end.  In reality however I wouldn't expect the a diagonalized matrix.  The ones would appear randomly distributed.

```
ID      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
8257    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2491    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9693    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7217    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3931    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7943    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3482    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1566    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7905    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
5645    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
7528    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
7902    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1695    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1986    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
9109    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920309/pivot-a-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-multiple-columns-like-reshape-cast-in-r/26920744#26920744

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109551/how-to-group-by-multiple-columns-and-then-transpose-in-hive/30115436#30115436

Comment: Those answers should help but with 1500 options, that will be a lot of repetitive code, but at the moment it is the only solution I know of (until someone implements https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3776)